# Mod_Rewrite Subdomain to Folder on Root Domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I currently have a domain that looks like this:

```
sub.domain.com OR sub.domain.com/folder
```

and I would like to direct that to:

```
domain.com/sub or domain.com/sub/folder
```

I can't figure out how to do this though. I've tried a bunch of different mod_rewrites and I've searched here and Google, it just isn't working. I'm not any good with mod_rewrite though so I'm not too surprised.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.yourdomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.yourdomain\.com/sub/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. I still get an "Oops! Google Chrome could not find mobile.qikdrop.com" (Or the equivalent in other browsers) whenever I visit the subdomain on the site. If it means anything, I haven't officially setup a subdomain in my cpanel. I didn't think that would matter though.